# can't find less loader and rules in webpack.conf

Tags: reactjs, webpack, less

I want to add Less support to a React project. According to these links:

[Adding SASS or LESS support to create-react-app](https://medium.com/@giordano.cardillo/adding-sass-or-less-support-to-create-react-app-38cbe6c370ce)

[React + CSS Modules + LESS + Webpack 4](https://medium.com/@joseph0crick/react-css-modules-less-webpack-4-a50d902d0a3)

I ejected project and installed less and less-loader, but I can't find rules section in webpack.config.js.
Why my config file is not like the config file in these two pages? (webpack version is 4.1.0)

How can I add Less support to my project?

[image]

If I add

```
  {
    loader: require.resolve('less-loader'),
  },
```

to file config, I'll get "Failed to compile" error

Cannot read property 'denominator' of undefined
      in ...\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.css (line 2100, column 2)

Comment: I have to mention that I can't add       {
        loader: require.resolve('less-loader'),
      },
to config file

Comment: But isn't bootstrap using `sass` these days?

Comment: @jayarjo I don't know, this is my first time using less or sass.

Comment: Try to swap it for `sass-loader`.

Comment: Also I just noticed that bootstrap file is from `dist\css\`, so it should be a pure css already, why do you even consider adding less loader to the rules?

Comment: @jayarjo when I change it to `sass-loader` I will get a syntax error at my sass file, and If I change the file type to scss, it will work fine

Comment: Finally, I found my solution. I just need to compile sass file to css file with `node-sass`

Answer (score 0):

Those tutorials are based on the old `CRA`, in the latest one they merged dev and prod files and did some additional mumbo jumbo to make it more "concise". One of those things was extracting CSS loaders into a standalone helper function - `getStyleLoaders()`. The `rules` section is below and the output of `getStyleLoaders` is merged onto it at an appropriate point.

In general what you are doing by appending your loader at the end of `loaders` array, is correct. And the error is not on the `webpack` side. It's rather thrown by `less-loader` not being able to interpret the file, because of invalid syntax inside.